# Is it possible to use webpack with a library that uses dependency injection?

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, aws-lambda

I'm pretty new to webpack so apologies if this is an obvious answer. I'm currently trying to deploy a typescript lambda api to AWS using this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-lambda-api

The library uses Inversify for dependency injection: https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS

The library also advises building by just using zip but I'd like to use webpack if I can.

I currently have two files for my api, a main api.ts file and then a controller.ts file. Currently the api class finds the controllers using the same lines as in the ts-lambda-api docs:

```
const controllersPath = [path.join(__dirname, "controllers")]
const app = new ApiLambdaApp(controllersPath, appConfig)
```

As a result I need the controller directory to be available to the api.ts class once it's been bundled. Currently my webpack config looks like this:

```
    import path = require('path')
    import webpack = require('webpack')
    
    const config: webpack.Configuration = {
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.js\.map$/, use: "ignore-loader" },
                { test: /\.d\.ts$/, use: "ignore-loader" }
            ]
        },
        mode: 'production',
        entry: {
            my_api: ['./src/my-api.js'],
        },
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
            filename: '[name]/main.js',
            library: '[name]',
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
        },
        target: 'node',
        externals: [/aws-sdk.*/, 'aws-lambda']
    };
    export default config
```

How can I add to it to allow my api access to the other classes it needs? The webpack docs have a page on multiple entry points (https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/#multi-page-application) but that doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for as it gives me multiple bundles.

I can put multiple files into one bundle by doing something like:

```
api: ['./src/api.js','./src/controllers/controller.js],
```

Although this won't then work with the Injectable annotations. Anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get around this issue by manually loading in the controllers following the section in the ts-lambda-api docs on how to do so.